# looping over AWK commands doesn't work

Tags: bash, awk

I have a huge dictionary file that contains each word in each line, and would like to split the files by the first character of the words.

a.txt --> only contains the words that start with a

I used this awk commands to successfully extract words that start with b.

```
  awk 'tolower($0)~/^b/{print}' titles-sorted.txt > b.txt
```

Now I wanted to iterate this for all alphabets

```
  for alphabet in {a..z} 
    do
        awk 'tolower($0)~/^alphabet/{print}' titles-sorted.txt > titles-links/^alphabet.txt
    done
```

But the result files contain no contents. What did I do wrong? I don't even know how to debug this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your awk program is in single quotes, there will not be any shell variable expansion.  In this example:

```
awk 'tolower($0)~/^alphabet/{print}' titles-sorted.txt > titles-links/^alphabet.txt
```

...you are looking for the lines that begin with the literal string `alphabet`.

This would work:

```
awk "tolower(\$0)~/^$alphabet/{print}" titles-sorted.txt > titles-links/$alphabet.txt
```

Note several points:

- We are using double quotes, which does not inhibit shell variable expansion.
- We need to escape the `$` in `$0`, otherwise the shell would expand that.
- We need to replace `alphabet` with `$alphabet`, because that's how you refer to shell variables.
- We need to replace `^alphabet` with `$alphabet` in the filename passed to `>`.

You could also transform the shell variable into an awk variable with `-v`, and do this:

```
for alphabet in {a..z} ; do
    awk -valphabet=$alphabet 'tolower($0)~"^"alphabet {print}' /usr/share/dict/words > words-$alphabet.txt
done
```